# Race between System.out and System.err in java

Tags: java, synchronization, system.out, system.err

Please consider this java code:

```
public class CMain {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("A");
            System.err.println("B");
        }

    }
}
```

By a quick look at the code, some of us may think **the output has to be the print of As and Bs alternatively.** However is not! It is a random appearance of 10 A characters and  10 B ones. Something like this:

[image]

Why is that? and what is the solution for it so that the As and Bs gets displayed alternatively ( A B A B A B ...)
Before I ask this question, I checked several other similar questions for solution and non worked for my case! I have brought some of them here:

- [Synchronization and System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/synchronization-and-system-out-println)
- [Java: synchronizing standard out and standard error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121786/java-synchronizing-standard-out-and-standard-error)
- [Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)
  **PS.** I am using Eclipse as my IDE

Comment: Those are two different streams that happen to be merged into the same console. If you want everything at a single place and in a given order, why don't you use a single stream (out OR err)?

Comment: I think the answer is in your second link "The problem is that it's the responsibility of the terminal emulator (in your case, Eclipse) to process the standard output and the standard error of your application. Without communicating with the terminal emulator, you can never be sure that out and err are displayed in the right order. Therefore, I would consider printing everything on err and redirect it to a file. You can still use out for clean user interaction."

Comment: Both streams are synchronized, but not on the same lock, so you should expect some interleaving... However, each stream, individually, will be ordered.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205

Comment: @owlstead which basically says: by design.  ;-)

Comment: @assylias I've got the gut feeling that it *can* be fixed, as Eclipse should have enough control over the streams, but it's design is indeed not able to handle it, with 2 threads

Comment: @DocMax No not really, that answer does not fix anything, these are println statements, and both streams should be auto-flushed. Actually, it is an incorrect answer even if it has +12. Interesting.

Comment: Cgraphics @KevinDTimm says you are using Eclipse, but I cannot find that anywhere in your question. Could you indicate your runtime?

Comment: Yap! I am using Eclipse, what do you mean by runtime?

Answer (score 12):

```
Why does this happen?
```

This is because `out` and `err` are two different output streams. However, both of them print on console. So you do not see them as different streams. Moreover, when you do `out.println()`, it is not guaranteed that you will see the output on the console as soon as the statement gets executed. Instead, the strings are usually(depends on the system) stored in an output buffer (if you will) which is processed later by the system to put the output from the buffer onto the screen.

```
Solution :(
```

Although, as **Eng.Fouad** pointed out that you can use `setOut(System.err)` or `setErr(System.out)` to make them ordered, I would still not suggest doing that when you are actually putting this in an application (only use it for debugging purposes).

What the proposed solution does is that it will end up using only one stream for both the standard output and the standard error, which I do not think is a good thing to do.

Comment: I guess that depends on the system, Ankit...

Comment: @owlstead yes ( I am assuming you are talking about the buffering)

Answer (score 6):

They are different `OutputStream`s. If you really need to guarantee the order of printing them, use:

```
System.setErr(System.out);
```

or

```
System.setOut(System.err);
```

Comment: This would likely work, but you would loose the highlighting that Eclipse applies.

Comment: @owlstead Well this is the same as replacing the System.err.println("B"); with System.out.println("B");

Comment: @Cgraphics Yes, it is almost the same. It would be something like having 2 references to the same stream.

Comment: @Cgraphics of course, but there is a difference between (temporarily) changing `System.out` or `System.err` to be able to debug correctly in Eclipse and altering each and every one of the `System.out.println` statements...

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two separate streams, the output you are giving is possible.

Comment: Depends on the system, both `System.out` and `System.err` are auto flushed by default. It's eclipse that does not detect the order in which bytes or characters are written. They are necessarily in order as `println()` should only return *after* flushing the stream.

Comment: you are right, I totally agree with you. That is why the order of A/B is possible. There can be any order too.