# Spring AOP execute order

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I am new in Spring AOP, and this is my codes for testing:

Target inside `com.kk.entity`package:

```
@Component
public class AopTargetOne {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private String address;

    //getter and setters omitted
}

@Component
public class AopTargetSecond {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    //getter and setters omitted
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class VariableCheckAspect {

    //intercept all the setter methods
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.kk.entity.*.set*(..))")
    private void aopIsSetMethod() {

    }

    @Before("com.kk.aop.VariableCheckAspect.aopIsSetMethod() && args(val,..)")
    public void checkSetValue(JoinPoint joinpoint, String val) {
        System.err.println("******** Start check set value  with method *********** " + joinpoint.getSignature());
        System.out.println("value is:" + val);
        System.err.println("********  End ****");
    }
}
```

Application:

```
    AopTargetOne ah = context.getBean(AopTargetOne.class);
    ah.setAddress("aopholder address");
    ah.setEmail("aopholder email");
    ah.setName("aopholder name");

    AopTargetSecond ak = (AopTargetSecond) context.getBean("aopTargetSecond");
    ak.setName("aopkepper name");
    ak.setEmail("aopkepper email");
    ak.setAge(23);
```

And I got the output:

```
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetOne.setAddress(String)
********  End ****
value is:aopTargetOne address
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetOne.setEmail(String)
********  End ****
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetOne.setName(String)
********  End ****
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetTwo.setName(String)
********  End ****
value is:aopTargetOne email
value is:aopTargetOne name
value is:aopTargetTwo name
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetTwo.setEmail(String)
********  End ****
value is:aopTargetTwo email
```

Which confused me! It seems that the code does not run with the normal order.

While I expect the output like this:

```
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetOne.setAddress(String)
value is:aopTargetOne address
********  End ****
******** Start check set value  with method *********** void com.kk.entity.AopTargetOne.setEmail(String)
value is:aopTargetOne email
********  End ****
....
```

What's the problem? Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a result of you performing output on two different output streams. You're writing to both `err` and `out`. [These don't necessarily get flushed in the same order (between streams).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147302/race-between-system-out-and-system-err-in-java)

```
System.err.println(..);
System.out.println(..);
```

Write to the same `OutputStream` and you'll see your expected output.

If we remove the output containing stars, we get

```
value is:aopTargetOne address
value is:aopTargetOne email
value is:aopTargetOne name
value is:aopTargetTwo name
value is:aopTargetTwo email
```

which is in the exact order you set them.

Comment: also you can flush using System.out.flush() and System.err.flush()