# Handling Exception in finally block

Tags: java, exception

Hi I have written below code. After each execution it is displaying output in a different order.

```
 public class ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[5];
        try {
            System.out.println("Accessing sixth element" + a[5]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally block start");
            try {
                double divide = a[3] / 0;
                System.out.println("Divide result:" + divide);
            } catch (ArithmeticException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Finall block end");
        }
        System.out.println("rest of the code");
    }

}
```

first run output:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at com.sanju.exceptionHandling.ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.main(ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.java:11)
    java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
finally block start
    at com.sanju.exceptionHandling.ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.main(ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.java:17)
Finall block end
rest of the code
```

second run output:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at com.sanju.exceptionHandling.ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.main(ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.java:11)
finally block start
Finall block end
rest of the code
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.sanju.exceptionHandling.ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.main(ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.java:17)
```

Third run output:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at com.sanju.exceptionHandling.ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.main(ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.java:11)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.sanju.exceptionHandling.ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.main(ExcetionInFinallyBlockDemo1.java:17)
finally block start
Finall block end
rest of the code
```

Could you please explain why it is printing in different order each time ?

Comment: Note that `System.out.println()` is not synchronized.

Comment: What environment are you executing? In Eclipse, Output pane is not synchronized...

Comment: I am using Eclipse IDE. and jdk 1.6

Comment: @Usagi Miyamoto what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the two output streams System.out and System.err are buffered independently.

Although i don't yet fully understand why - my first answer - flushing the buffers - actually don't help (as bowmore suggests) and it seems to be impossible to do this without using your own synchronized solution.

An easy workaround is using only one buffer for err and out like this:

```
System.setErr(System.out);
```

as already mentioned here: [Race between System.out and System.err in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147302/race-between-system-out-and-system-err-in-java)

Comment: Flushing won't magically synchronize the two buffers.

Comment: Youre right - but i was expecting the output reaching the output-buffer (the console) the moment flush returns. Obviously it doesn't.

Comment: Alternatively, in his snippet he can simply print stacktraces to System.out : `e.printStacktrace(System.out)`