# System.out.println(); and System.err.println(); printing interchangeably

Tags: java

This code is part of a program.

```
System.out.print("Enter your deposit amount: ");
double deposit = scanner.nextDouble();
bankObj.deposit(deposit); //this method will print a syserr if the number entered is negative
if (deposit > 0) {
    System.out.println("Thank you for depositing the amount of "+deposit+" to account number "+bankObj.accountNum+".");
}
    System.out.println("Program exiting.");
```

Output:

```
Enter your deposit amount: -2
//sometimes it will print.
Program exiting.
Account.deposit(...): cannot deposit negative amount. //This is from the deposit method
//or
Account.deposit(...): cannot deposit negative amount. //This is from the deposit method
Program exiting.
```

Why is this happening? I tried putting it outside loops and statements (those might be the problem) but the behavior didn't change. I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are two different output streams, the order in which they are invoked is not the only thing that matters. They might flush their contents towards the console at a different time.

Edit: after a bit more digging [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13656997/1864167) indicates that it might be an (unresolved) [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205) as well. It's been open for 10 years, don't get your hopes up on a fix anytime soon.

Comment: So is there a way to fix it, like at least making the syserr appear before the sysout?

Comment: Both `System.out` and `System.err` are a `Printstream` so you can try manually flushing them (`System.out.flush()`). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html