# Problems to validate a number in try-catch block in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, try-catch

I am trying to create a method to introduce an int with NetBeans, but I have a problem when I run the method, the order of console messages is not correct, someone knows what the problem is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System. in );
    int num;
    boolean error;

    public int introducirDatos()
    {
        do
        {
            error = false;
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero: ");
                num = Integer.valueOf(teclado.nextLine());

            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Debe introducir un número y sin decimales, vuelve a intentarlo.\n");
                error = true;
            }
        } while (error == true);
        return num;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're not very clear about the problem that you're having. Specifically what output are you getting? What output were you expecting to get?

Comment: The problem is the order in which System.out.print and System.err.print appear when I run the program, they appear mixed up.

Comment: What are you expecting and what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are running the code in an IDE - IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse. The line `System.out.println("Introduzca un número entero: ");` prints to standard OUT, but `System.err.println("Debe introdu...` prints to standard ERROR. That's why the output gets messed up. Replace `System.err` with `System.out` for the messages being printed nicely one after another.
BTW you haven't specified which language you are using. Is it Java? You might want to update the question tags.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That was exactly the problem I had. 
Can you tell me why it happens, why I can't use System.err?

Comment: In general, each program has 3 standard input-output (I/O) channels. You can read about them in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams. Stderr is usually separated from stdout so that they can be treated differently - for instance, all errors written into a file and all messages printed on screen. The problem happened because of how the IDE (Netbeans) treats the streams, and I assume your original program would run correctly in a terminal. I don't think you need to print to stderr, since your program runs in an interactive mode and you actually want to see the error messages.

Comment: You may also find the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121786/java-synchronizing-standard-out-and-standard-error useful