# Is there any priority between multiple try/catch execution in java?

Tags: java

In the below program, sometime i get following output:

```
Number Format Execption For input string: "abc"
123
```

and sometime:

```
123
Number Format Execption For input string: "abc"
```

Is there any priority between try/catch block or priority between System.out and System.err?

What is the reason of random output?

code:

```
String str1 = "abc";
String str2 = "123";

     try{
         int firstInteger = Integer.parseInt(str1);
         System.out.println(firstInteger);
     }
     catch(NumberFormatException e){
         System.err.println("Number Format Execption " + e.getMessage());
     }

       try{
         int SecondInteger = Integer.parseInt(str2);
         System.out.println(SecondInteger);
         }
     catch(NumberFormatException e){
         System.err.println("Number Format Execption " + e.getMessage());
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

Comment: (If that *were* the case, then all bets of code execution order would be forfeit... without even introducing new threads... and thus not sanely plausible :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the try/catch and everything to do with that you are writing to System.out and System.err; they are two different streams and you can't control the order of their interleaving as they are written to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the streams explicitly,

```
System.out.flush();
System.err.flush();
```