# Getting different output from main

Tags: java

```
package com.test.scjp;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestGeneric {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
            TestGeneric t = new TestGeneric();
        //t.test(l);
            System.out.println("Test");
            l=t.test(l);
            System.out.println("Test2");

            System.out.println(l.get(0));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public List<String> test(List l){
        System.out.println("Test0");
        l.add(new Integer(1));
        System.out.println("Test1");
        return l;
    }
}
```

When I run this code 20 times I am getting different outputs:

**Output 1:**

```
Test
Test0
Test1
Test2
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.test.scjp.TestGeneric.main(TestGeneric.java:16)
```

**Output 2:**

```
Test
Test0
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at com.test.scjp.TestGeneric.main(TestGeneric.java:16)
Test1
Test2
```

Comment: Test
Test0
Test1
Test2
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at com.test.scjp.TestGeneric.main(TestGeneric.java:16)

Comment: `l.add(new Integer(1))` <-- you are trying to add an integer to a list containing String elements.

Comment: Output in console comes from two streams, `System.out`, and `System.err`, and as you can see, sometimes output from `err` can be printed while printing output from `out`. To make it more readable IDEs like Eclipse use different color on `err`.

Comment: @Pshemo: you should make that an answer

Comment: @JBNizet Nah, answer should fully explain this problem. I proffered to post general idea as comment and let others explain it better, since I am too tired and going to sleep now. Goodnight all :D

Answer (score 2):

`System.out` and `System.err` work on different threads. Both threads access a shared resource (the *console*) at different times.

See also [Random printing order for System.out & System.err calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594537/random-printing-order-for-system-out-system-err-calls) and [Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

Answer (score 0):

Inside test, your list isnt Generic - so you're allowed to add any Object to it.

The problem is that outside of it you're using a List that is restricted to Strings.

Its this conflict thats causing your problems.