# Printing all System.out.println() statements sequentially

Tags: java

I am trying to print some statements in java using System.out.println() statements but they aren't printing sequentially.

```
if(us02_birth_b4_marriage())
{
    System.out.println("All user stories passed succesfully");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("There are following errors: ");
    for(String failString: failures)
    {
        System.err.println(failString);
    }
    //System.exit(0);
}

System.out.println("Individual");
System.out.format("%-10s%-20s%-10s%-15s%-10s%-15s%-15s%-20s%-20s\n", "ID", "Name", "Gender", "Birthday", "Age", "Alive", "Death", "Child", "Spouse");
```

The method is defined at the beginning of the class. Does that make any difference? Please see the output here [Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aSXS.png)

Comment: What do you mean sequentially, in this context? If you mean by the order it is written in your code, that is not going to happen unless your first `if` statement is always `true`.

Comment: By order I mean, It prints "Individual" first, then "There are following errors: ", then System.err.println() and then System.out.format() statement. And this sequence keeps on changing everytime. Ideally, it should print, "There are following errors", System.err.println(), "Individual", System.out.format().

Comment: You will need to write a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random printing order for System.out & System.err calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594537/random-printing-order-for-system-out-system-err-calls) and [System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1883321/12299000)

Comment: you could try to force flush for System.out and System.err after each println, however, I believe it's already auto flushing after each new line character. But might be something to try

Comment: @pavel.lazar I tried putting flush after every statement but it still gave me the same bug. What I found out is that there is no synchronization available and its a long-lasting bug in eclipse. However, trying in another  IDE may help.

Comment: Well yes, it might.  But it won't fix the problem in general.  The real answer is to adjust your expectations.  Don't rely on any specific ordering of console output when you write to both `System.out` *and* `System.err`.  FWIW, it is not really an Eclipse bug.

Comment: @StephenC Please check - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205. It says "This has been improved since 2.0, but since 
writing/reading from out/err streams is non-deterministic (i.e. we have 
separate threads reading output from each stream), the result can be non-
deterministic."

Comment: I already looked at it.  It is marked as FIXED.  Meaning that any residual strange behavior is not regarded as a bug anymore.   (Or ... if you are using an old version of Eclipse, upgrade to 4.13 == 2019-09).

Comment: Either way, the Java specs provide no guarantees on the interleaving of output to different streams redirected to the same place by the external environment.  So the old behavior of Eclipse is not buggy from the perspective of the Java specs.  (This is probably why it took such a long tome for the developers to get around to improving the behavior.)

Comment: @StephenC Alright! I get it now, I guess. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are writing some messages to `System.out` and others to `System.err`.  This may result in the lines being in an unexpected order (depending on what you expect ...).  This is *primarily* because `System.out` and `System.err` are different streams with different (Java side) buffering characteristics.

Given the way you are running your application, they happen to write to the same place; i.e. your console.  But even so, the OS does not guarantee that the interleaving of standard output and standard error lines will correspond exactly to the order that the application wrote them.

Solution: if you want a guarantee that that the lines will appear on the console in the order that your code writes them, you must write them to the same stream.