# Why is System.err slower than System.out in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, stderr, stdio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

Why this code

```
    System.err.println("err");
    System.out.println("out");
```

prints

```
out
err
```

on Eclipse console?

UPDATE

The same code prints in correct order if I run it from command line.

UPDATE

If I fix it as

```
    System.err.println("err");
    Thread.sleep(5);
    System.out.println("out");
```

It prints correctly in Eclipse too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not slower; they're just not necessarily [flushed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush%28%29) in order. You can fix that, however:

```
System.err.println("err");
System.err.flush();
System.out.println("out");
```

---

Okay, so this appears to be a known Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32205

Comment: But println also calls flush(). See PrintStream.println.

Comment: I'm not convinced that your (read: Eclipse's) `println()` implementation does actually call `flush()`.

Comment: It does. I debugged it, it comes to java.io.PrintStream.newLine() where it calls flush().

Comment: See my edit. Apparently it's just a long-standing Eclipse bug.