# Difference in calling sequence while rethrowing exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Consider the following class with methods: a() calling b() which in turn calls c().

```
public class ReThrower {

    public static void a(int a1){
        try{
           a1+=1;
           b(a1);
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught at a");
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public static void b(int b1){
        try{
            b1+=1;
            c(b1);
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught at b");
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public static void c(int c1){
        int zero=0,result;
        try{
            result=c1/zero;
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught at c");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a(5);
    }

}
```

When i ran the above code, the initial output received was:

```
Exception caught at c
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
Exception caught at b
Exception caught at a
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.c(ReThrower.java:31)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.b(ReThrower.java:20)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.a(ReThrower.java:10)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.main(ReThrower.java:46)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.c(ReThrower.java:31)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.b(ReThrower.java:20)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.a(ReThrower.java:10)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.main(ReThrower.java:46)
```

Even before the c() printed the complete stacktrace, the sysout included in b() and a() has already been executed.
However,When i ran it again, the output changed as such:

```
    Exception caught at c
Exception caught at b
Exception caught at a
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.c(ReThrower.java:31)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.b(ReThrower.java:20)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.a(ReThrower.java:10)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.main(ReThrower.java:46)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.c(ReThrower.java:31)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.b(ReThrower.java:20)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.a(ReThrower.java:10)
    at com.atul.security.ReThrower.main(ReThrower.java:46)
```

Given that this is single threaded, why is there a change in behaviour in multiple runs?

Answer (score 3):

`e.printStacktrace` prints to `System.err` whereas you print the rest of the lines with `System.out`. And when you print to both streams [the result can look out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order).

Comment: But it's not multithreaded - surely this interleaving would be deterministic?

Comment: Can't see why; stream buffering is asynchronous. @assylias is correct here.