# order of execution of static method

Tags: java, static-methods

```
public class Sample {

    public void method()
    {
        System.out.println("normal hai");   
    }
    public static void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("static hai");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample s = null;
        s.method1();
        s.method(); 
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.csvfile.sample.main(Sample.java:22)

static hai
```

Why has the order changed? It should output:

```
static hai
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.csvfile.sample1.main(Sample.java:22)
```

Comment: @kocko Because that's the order he called the methods in...

Comment: Calling a static method on an instance variable is bad coding style to begin with. Always call static methods on the class itself: `sample1.method1()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order

Comment: @Marvin: Different issue.  In that question, different streams were written to.

Comment: @EricJ.: OP wonders about the order of his "static hai" (written to `System.out`) and his stack trace (usually written to `System.err`). I don't see how this is a different issue.

Comment: Ah... you're right.  I did not consider that the exception is written to stderr.

Answer (score 16):

The issue you  have is that the `Exception` is printed to `System.err` while your code prints to `System.out`.

So, without a badly named class (`PascalCase` please) we can do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final System system = null;
    system.out.println("Odd");
    System.out.println(system.toString());
}
```

And the output I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
Odd
    at com.boris.testbench.App.main(App.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

So they're actually *interleaved*. i.e. the order of the output is **undefined** as there are two output streams being printed to the console.

Changing the code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final System system = null;
    system.err.println("Odd");
    System.err.println(system.toString());
}
```

Produces the desired result.

You could also catch the exception and print it to `System.out` to achieve the same effect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final System system = null;
    system.out.println("Odd");
    try {
        System.out.println(system.toString());
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

**P.S.** I'm sure you know this, but you should never call a `static` method on an instance of the `class`. You should always call the `static` method on the `class` itself. So in your example, you should always do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    sample1 s = new sample1();
    s=null;
    sample1.method1();
    s.method(); 
}
```

Comment: You could probably also achieve the effect by calling `System.out.flush()` before throwing the exception.

Comment: @Quincunx assuming that your terminal emulator doesn't do some other buffering and all sorts of unknowns - yes, ought to work.

Answer (score 5):

That is because the `exception` is printed to STDERR and `System.out.println()` is printed to STDOUT and both streams are not synchronized.

If you call it a second time the order can change.

Comment: @Ramaiah.S i wrote it `can` not `must`

Answer (score 1):

This is because out and err are two different output streams. However, both of them print on console. So you do not see them as different streams. Try the below code and check output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.err.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a good to know thing in Java:

In Java there are several types of init fileds:
let`s see an example:

```
public class HunarianEngineer{

static{
       System.out.println("1.This is a static block, called when the JVM pull in the class first time ever");
 }

{
 System.out.println("2.This is an instance block, runs before constructor");
}

public HungarianEngineer(){
     System.out.println("3.I`m a constructor");
}

}//EndOfClass
```

Read more about them:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html
or here:

http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/initialization-blocks-constructors-and-their-order-of-execution/

Comment: How does this in any way relate to the question asked?