# Why java execution order is different each time & Value comparison is wrong

Tags: java, equals

I am having doubt on System.err.print() execution control. The order in which statements are printed is differs for each execution.   I do have 2 questions.

Following is the code

```
public class AutoBoxingProblems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        problem1();

        problem2();

   }

    private static void problem2() {
        System.out.println("Problem2");
        // Be very careful, Even values are same but two different objects, this will give you equal
        Integer i1 = 100;
        Integer i2 = 100;

        if (i1 == i2) {
            System.err.println("i1 and i2 is equal  ==> Problem2");
        } else {
            System.err.println("i1 and i2 is not equal  ==> Problem2");
        }
    }

    private static void problem1() {
        System.out.println("Problem1");
        // Be very careful, Even values are same, this will give you unequal
        Integer i1 = 260;
        Integer i2 = 260;
        if (i1 == i2) {
            System.err.println("i1 and i2 is equal  ==> Problem1");
        } else {
            System.err.println("i1 and i2 is not equal  ==> Problem1");
        }
    }
}



  //Output
    //Some times
    Problem1
    Problem2               
    i1 and i2 is not equal ==> Problem1 
    i1 and i2 is equal ==> Problem2

    //Some times
    Problem1
   i1 and i2 is not equal ==> Problem1 
   i1 and i2 is equal ==> Problem2
   Problem2
```

**Question1:**  Why in each execution,  print statements order differs?

**Question2:**  Why one method prints the values are equal and other method says not equal? (To compare values, we should use 'equals' only. But why '==' operator behaves weird?)

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637936/java-integer-equals-vs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 128==128 return false but 127==127 return true when converting to Integer wrappers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-does-128-128-return-false-but-127-127-return-true-when-converting-to-integ). This is the dreaded autoboxing!

Comment: OK. Now I understood the answer(Caching Integer Objects) for 2nd question.  But Why print order differs each time?(1st question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JLS 5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, or a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127 (inclusive), then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. **`It is always the case that r1 == r2`**.

You are getting same object for value `100` because JVM cache it.
From [Immutable Objects / Wrapper Class Caching](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_gotchas#Immutable_Objects_.2F_Wrapper_Class_Caching)

> 256 Integer objects are created in the range of -128 to 127 which are all stored in an Integer array. This caching functionality can be seen by looking at the inner class, IntegerCache, which is found in Integer:

That's why below statement is true:

```
Integer i1 = 100; // return  Cached object
Integer i2 = 100; // return Cached object
if (i1 == i2) { //both object are same that's why its true
```

For `Integer i1 = 260;` it's return new object that why `if (i1 == i2)` is false.

```
Integer i1 = 260; // return new object
Integer i2 = 260; // return new object
if (i1 == i2) { // both object are different that's why false
```

**Question1**

Because `System.err.println` and `System.out.println` uses different threads. so they can print any time, **but the order of print in each stream should be same means first problem1 then problem2**

Comment: OK. Now I understood the answer(Caching Integer Objects) for 2nd question. But Why print order differs each time?(1st question)

Answer (score 0):

i1 and i2 are `Integer` objects, so you must compare calling the correct methods and not using ==

The printing order looks random because the system.err has its own stream 
You need to add a flush to force the stream to be printed everytime after the

```
System.err.println("i1 a
```

....

Comment: OK. Now I understood the answer(Caching Integer Objects) for 2nd question. But Why print order differs each time?(1st question)

Answer (score 0):

`int` type is a primitive, you can compare it using `if (i1 == i2)` if you've declared it like

```
    int i1 = 100;
    int i2 = 100;
```

whereas the 'Integer' type is an object and objects can be checked using `.equals` like

```
 if (i1.equals(i2){...}
```

But may return true if those reference the same object.

**So what's wrong in using == then ?**

> Simply it compares object references and checks to see if the two operands point to the same object not equivalent objects.

Comment: OK. Now I understood the answer(Caching Integer Objects) for 2nd question. But Why print order differs each time?(1st question)

Comment: @RajkumarSeenappa There is no order differs, It's printing one from `problem1` and pring another from `problem2` as your codes.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is an object in java. When you are comparing

```
if (i1 == i2)
```

then you are comparing their references, not there values. You should use the primitive data type 'int' instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Question1: Why in each execution, print statements order differs?**

You are using two different output stream `System.out` and `System.err`.

Output streams are cached so all the write goes into this memory buffer. After a period of quiet, they are actually written out.

[Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

[Java IO: System.in, System.out, and System.error](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/system-in-out-error.html)