# Unexpected output using System.err.println() in java

Tags: java

I tried executing the following print statements in JAVA, but the output which I got is unexpected. Output is jumbled.

```
public class AsyncTestClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("1");
    System.out.println("2");
    System.out.println("3");
    System.out.println("4");
    System.out.println("5");
    System.err.println("Error");
    System.out.println("6");
    System.out.println("7");
    System.out.println("8");
    System.out.println("9");
    System.out.println("10");       
   }
 }
```

first run Output:

```
1
Error
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

second run output:

```
     1
2
3
4
5
Error
6
7
8
9
10
```

third run output:

```
    1
Error
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Why I am getting different outputs for the same code??
Thanks

Comment: That's because `System.out.println()` is buffered, and `System.err.println()` isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different streams and they flushed at different times.

```
System.out.flush();
System.err.flush();
```

You can take help from this [Stack-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

Comment: Thanks , i got this link too

Comment: I just give you the link of answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

They are different streams and are flushed at different times.

If you put

```
System.out.flush();
System.err.flush();
```

Inside your code, it will work as expected.