# Synchronizing two threads printing to stderr

Tags: java, multithreading

It is my understanding that synchronization of two threads using java synchronize and notify() and wait() methods works like this:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Business business = new Business();
        // 子线程
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                    try {
                        business.sonBusiness(i);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            business.mainBusiness(i);
        }
    }
}
class Business {
    public void mainBusiness(int i) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
                System.out.println("主线程第" + i + "轮，第" + j + "次");
            }
            this.notify();
            this.wait();
        }
    }
    public void sonBusiness(int i) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 30; j++) {
                System.err.println("子线程第" + i + "轮，第" + j + "次");
            }
            this.notify();
            this.wait();
        }
    }
}
```

However the output that I see (see below) tells me that the synchronization is not workign as I expect. I think the main thread and the new thread may run "one by one" and in most cases they do. But I get the following output. I don't know how to explain it , please give me a hand .

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? If two threads can run at once?

Comment: @UnholySheep I think when one thread is printing , the other one must be   waiting to be notified . But above output means no .

Comment: You can try to print to stderr in main and son Business. Or flush stdout after printing.

Comment: i think root cause here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order

Comment: You can't call `wait` until you make sure the thing you are waiting for hasn't already happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because you are printing them to `System.out` and `System.err`at the same time. In IDE they may be the same console, but not synchronized very well.

Comment: Likely. System.out is buffered. While System.err is not.

Comment: @Matthias I've never thought about this, but it's logic since error should be seen immediately. : )

Comment: You mean the way 2 theads run as expected but the console cheated me ?

Comment: @passion Exactly.

Comment: This is it. Try replacing `System.err` with `System.out` and you will get the expected output.