# Java - ThreadPool synchronized problem when i try printing

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, threadpool

i use ThreadPool class and when i try to print the matrix this is what i get:

```
 Enter number of threads:
 5
 Enter number of matrices:
 3
 Enter number diminesion:
 2
 [1][1][0][1]
 [0][1]
 -----------------------------------------------
 [0][0]
 [1][0]
 -----------------------------------------------

 [0][1]
 -----------------------------------------------
```

i try to synchronized but is still not working good, why?
and another question, when i try to use matrices queue from GenerateMatrix class in the main is say the queue is empty what id do wrong?
because what i try to do is to generate n matrix and after the generate is finish multiply all the matrices.

main:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Queue<int[][]> matrices = new LinkedList<int[][]>();

    System.out.println("Enter number of threads:");
    int numOfThreads = input.nextInt();

    ThreadPool pool = new ThreadPool(numOfThreads);

    System.out.println("Enter number of matrices:");
    int numOfMatrices = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter number diminesion:");
    int diminesion = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMatrices; i++) {
        GenerateMatrix generateMatrix = new GenerateMatrix(numOfMatrices, 
diminesion);
        pool.execute(generateMatrix);

    }

}
}
```

GenerateMatrix  class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class GenerateMatrix implements Runnable {

private int numOfMatrices;
private int dimension;
private static Queue<int[][]> matrices = new LinkedList<int[][]>();

public GenerateMatrix(int n, int d) {
    numOfMatrices = n;
    dimension = d;
}

public Queue<int[][]> getMatricesQueue() {
    return matrices;
}

public void run() {
    int[][] tempMatrix = new int[dimension][dimension];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempMatrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempMatrix.length; j++) {
            tempMatrix[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
        }
    }
    synchronized (this) {
        for (int k = 0; k < tempMatrix.length; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tempMatrix.length; j++) {
                System.out.print("[" + tempMatrix[k][j] + "]");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------- 
   ");

        matrices.add(tempMatrix);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `matrices` is empty in the class `Main` is because you never add anything to it. You create 2 variables called `matrices`, one in `Main`, one in `GenerateMatrices`.If you look in `Main`, you call:

`Queue<int[][]> matrices = new LinkedList<int[][]>();`

and then you never use it again, so it remains empty. If however you called `GenerateMatrices.getMatrices().length`, it should be non-zero (assuming you define `getMatrices()`.

As for why it is printing weirdly, the following SO answer should help: [Java: System.out.println and System.err.println out of order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883321/java-system-out-println-and-system-err-println-out-of-order)

In short, calls to `System.out.println()` are not immediately written to output, due to the high overhead of the system call. Instead, they are written to a buffer and, when the JVM is happy that more isn't going to arrive in the near future, the contents of the buffer is written to output. `System.out.flush()` forces this process to happen sooner, which may help you with what you need.

Alternatively, instead of using `synchronized (this) {...}` you can use `syncrhonized (System.out) {...}` to ensure no interleaving.

P.S.

`GenerateMatrices.matrices` probably shouldn't be static. If you create multiple instances of `GenerateMatrices`, you probably want them to have separate copies of `matrices`. And if not, you should probably create a class such as `MatrixStore` to make it clear what is happening.